# Possible to fix an element to top inside an absolute positioned div?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with pop up overlays in different parts of the page. Each overlay has a close button that I want to stay at the top.

The problem I'm having is that the overlays are positioned absolute (otherwise they're not relative to their parent) and when i try to position the close button as fixed it "fixes" to the whole page, not from within the overlay.

Parent (position: relative)
      Overlay: (position: absolute)
             Closer button: (position: ???)

I didn't paste all the code because it's long and it seems like this could be solved without it.

thanks!

**EDIT: The goal is to have the closer stay at the top even when scrolling. Sorry I wasn't very clear about that.**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have HTML "a bit like this".

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">X</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use `position: absolute` on the innermost div.

```
.A {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.B {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: Aqua;
}

.C {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lb5U/

Comment: Thanks Steve. I think I should have clarified that I want it to stay at the top even when scrolling, aka sticky. I've been researching and it seems the short answer is that it's only possible with JS or some serious hacking that may not be cross browser compatible.

Comment: Nah - you can use `position: fixed` for that - simples :) - here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/PbG4L/1/

Comment: We ended up isolating the content below the close button and using overflow: scroll and that worked fine.